# How to make this staggered 3D rotating text effect in AE?

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects

I saw this amazing moving poster... and I really want to know how to make this text animation!

So, i wanna know how to make that kind of spinning text. and what is that irregular glitch effext???

[image]

Comment: This is too broad, and it would require writing a full tutorial here - which is not what this site is about. What have you tried? Check [ask] to learn what kind of questions are allowed and [edit] your question to add details / make it more specific so we can help you.

Comment: But if you search for "after effects rotate text 3d on circle path" you'll find plenty of video tutorials to start, and from there you should be able to keep adapting until you get the effect you saw.

Comment: ------- What have you tried? -------